# adding a counting variable to an ostream overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was wondering if there was anyway to overload the ostream with a counting variable for instance

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, TYPE t,int i);
```

I need the int to help output part of an array and it would be a lot easier if I could just send an int through the overload

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
struct TypeOut
{
    TYPE _t;
    int _i;
};
```

and write function `ostream& operator << (ostream& out, TypeOut t);`

Comment: alright and then inside the function would just be something like.

    cout << t[i];

Comment: Then you can do like `t._t` and `t._i`